# Inkscape convert svg to png vertical text has different format

Tags: svg, png, inkscape

I find there is a problem when I use inkscape convert svg to png.

I run `inkscape filename.svg+xml --export-png=filename.png`.

this in the contrast of svg and png.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePIoW.jpg)

How can I unify the format ,thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an Inkscape bug. Perhaps you should report it to their bugtracker.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me which tool can convert svg to png with best effect  in centos.

Comment: not really, try them and see.

Comment: Do you obtain the same bug when doing an interactive export to PNG in inkscape? How is the SVG vertical text produced? (rotation of a text element?) You could post a minimal SVG file giving this bug.